# Background 'slides' not responsive in css

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a series of 'slides' on my website that work fine on a 1080p monitor, but do not scale at all on a phone/tablet. I've already tried a few different methods, not of which have worked.

http://pelicancottage.com.au has the images as they currently are, and here is the css for one of the 'slides'

```
#slide1{
background:url('../img/slide2.png') 50% 0 no-repeat fixed;
color: #fff;
height: 800px;  
margin: 0;
padding: 200px 0 260px 0;
background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Try to change 0 to 50% at background propertie

Comment: That didn't change anything...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the css media queries? This allows you to customize your layout depending on your screen-size as well as your device (an explanation of this is here-> http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-with-css3-media-queries).

Comment: Please consider posting some relevant codes as well, links only answers are not considered as good answers.

Answer (score 0):

try this
but for a phone you better change background. Can't go from 16:9 to whatever a phone uses.

```
#slide1 {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```